# How can I use gb_trees efficiently?

Tags: erlang

I am trying to use gb_trees to represent a data hierarchy. I am interested in using them because of the key_value property, and at the same time display hierarchy. I could use a simple example of how to manipulate them...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find a very good explanation on erlang data structures here: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/a-short-visit-to-common-data-structures

The above article has a benchmark of different data structures, including gb_trees: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/static/erlang/keyval_benchmark.erl

Comment: Where can I find some examples, code implementations and use cases of gb_trees data structure in erlang?